# Can't set empty title page background after beamer upgrade

Tags: beamer

**Update:** see [this bug report](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/494).

I just upgraded to beamer 3.52 and can no longer set an empty background color for `title page`.  Somehow the background color is always white (or I can set it to something else, but if I try to make it empty, it goes back to white).  I would like to print the title over a background drawing, and it now looks terrible.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\setbeamerfont*{title}{parent=structure, size=\Huge, series=\bfseries}

\title{My Titlepage That Doesn't Work}
\date{}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!50}
\setbeamercolor{title page}{bg=} % stays white
\maketitle
}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like with beamer 3.5:

[image]

That's exactly what I want--text printed over background.  Now here's what I get with beamer 3.52:

[image]

This is presumably some kind of bug, but because the version got deployed with arch linux's texlive package, I would ideally like to find a workaround.  Unfortunately, just setting the `title page.bg` to a solid color won't work in my non-minimal actual use case, because in my real use case I have a more complex drawing in the background.

I looked at the source code for `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` and it seems to be making a beamercolorbox with the title page template, so I don't understand why it is getting set to a white background.

Comment: Well, beamer 3.53 seems to work again, so ideally texlive will update this sooner than a year from now...

Comment: I run MacTeX2018, and version 3.53 of `beamer` was installed a week ago on my system. Please clarify what you mean by "ideally texlive will update this sooner than a year from now". FWIW, I can confirm that your MWE runs correctly when compiled with version 3.53 of `beamer`. (I haven't tried it withan earlier version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Joseph Wright in the bug report, you can use the newer version
3.53 of `beamer`. You can install it manually without touching the arch pacman
tarballs by creating the folder

```
~/texmf
```

Its structure is the same as

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist
```

So, you can create the `latex` folder in there and copy the up-to-date beamer
files (from e.g. ctan). Alternatively, you can

```
$ git clone https://github.com/josephwright/beamer
$ cd beamer
$ env texlua ./build.lua install
```

The bugfix is

```
diff --git a/base/beamerbasecolor.sty b/base/beamerbasecolor.sty
index 8d21e32..4dce70e 100644
--- a/base/beamerbasecolor.sty
+++ b/base/beamerbasecolor.sty
@@ -207,7 +207,7 @@
       \box\beamer@tempbox%
     \fi%
   \else%
-    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
+    \if@tempswa\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
       \usebeamercolor{\beamer@colbox@color}%
       \hskip-\beamer@colbox@colseps%
       \fboxsep=\z@\colorbox{bg}{%
@@ -216,7 +216,7 @@
         \hskip\beamer@colbox@colseps%
       }%
       \hskip-\beamer@colbox@colseps%
-      }%
+      }\fi%
     \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>\textwidth%
       \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox to\textwidth{\hskip0pt minus\beamer@leftmargin\relax\box\beamer@tempbox\hskip0pt minus\beamer@leftmargin\relax}%
     \fi%
```

You can try to patch that via `xpatch` or `regexpatch`, too.

Comment: Seems that Arch Linux can install some kind of "local `tlmgr`": https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-localmanager-git/ and  https://git.archlinux.org/users/remy/texlive-localmanager.git/tree/tllocalmgr#n809 Maybe that would be an option here.

Comment: Good advice, one could try that as well.